# API to get all user-permissions android

Tags: android, android-permissions

So I am actually developing an app where I need to display the list of all uses-permissions in android. The one we add to AndroidManifest.xml.

Is there any public API where I can get a list of all permissions as a json or something which I could use easily.

I searched and got [this list](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) .

But I need a api to which I could make an http request to get the list of permissions.

Like this

```
{
"permissions": [
    {
        "xmlTag": "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />",
        "name": "Camera"
    ........ somthing like this
    }
]
```

}

Comment: If you need it in Android, you can use PackageManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPermissionInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: @DanBaruch Actually I need it for javascript.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: @gtxtreme can you explain how do I use it as a API call? To get data as json etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this api, `PackageManager.getAllPermissionGroups()` to get all user permissions.

Comment: Actually I am not making an android app but an webapp. So I can't use that.